# roscore launch failed saying "You must specify a valid interface name"

Tags: roslaunch, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ros groovy recently, and now I got this error frequently when I use command "roscore":

---

... logging to /home/jingru/.ros/log/52f1ef44-c93e-11e2-8e1d-648099590658/roslaunch-Jingru-Lenovo-11463.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://Jingru-Lenovo:38033/
ros_comm version 1.9.44

## SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

- /rosdistro
- /rosversion

NODES

### You must specify a valid interface name.

After a system reboot, I can launch it successfully. Please help! Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63943/roscore-launch-failed-saying-%22you-must-specify-a-valid-interface-name%22/) by [Jingru](https://answers.ros.org/users/5018/jingru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-05-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved this with

```
sudo pip install --upgrade netifaces
```

(Similar to Jochen's answer above, this upgrades python netifaces.)

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2013-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've had the same problem on Ubuntu 12.04 and fixed it by installing python-netifaces from 12.10.

HTH

Jochen

---

Originally posted by [Jochen Sprickerhof](https://answers.ros.org/users/182/jochen-sprickerhof/) with karma: 46 on 2013-06-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lucien](https://answers.ros.org/users/5354/lucien/) on 2013-07-08**:
I had the same problem but I already installed python-netifaces from 12.04.
But I still got the same question.
How did you install python-netifaces from 12.10?